# Disable hidden duplicate field when selecting dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following form code that shows a drop down menu for Existing category if that is selected OR a text field if Add new category is selected.

This all works perfectly but I am trying to validate the fields and I cannot disable the duplicate field not chosen, so I cannot submit the form.

I am getting an empty field fail on the validation and the following error: An invalid form control with name='category' is not focusable.

I want to change the name OR disable it OR set a value of the hidden field so that it validates.

```
<tr>
    <td class="right bold">New or Existing Category: </td>
    <td class="capitalise">
    <select name="categoryType" id="categoryType" required>
        <option value="" selected='selected'>--Please Select--</option>
        <option value="existing">Existing Category - Select from Category list below</option>
        <option value="addNew">Add new Category - Add new Category in Text box below</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>   

<tr id="existing">
    <td class="right bold">Category: </td>
    <td class="capitalise">
    <select id="categoryExist" name="category" required>
        <option value='' selected='selected'>--Please Select--</option></select>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="addNew">
    <td class="right bold">Add Category: </td>
    <td class="capitalise">
        <input id="categoryNone" type="text" name="category" class="capitalise" required />
    </td>
</tr>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#categoryType").change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'existing') {
            $('#existing').show();
            $('#categoryNone').attr({name: "difcat", value: '000'});
        } else {
            $('#existing').hide();
        }
        if (this.value == 'addNew') {
            $('#addNew').show();
            $('#categoryExist').attr({name: "othercat", value: '000'});
        } else {
            $('#addNew').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I have also tried:

```
 $(["input:hidden, textarea:hidden, select:hidden"]).attr("disabled", false);
```

but it does not seem to work.

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LUeT9/

OK this is resolved, I changed the following, which disabled the non active validation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#categoryType").change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'existing') {
            $('#existing').show();
            $('#categoryNone').prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $('#existing').hide();
        }
        if (this.value == 'addNew') {
            $('#addNew').show();
            $('#categoryExist').prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $('#addNew').hide();
        }
        });
});
```

Comment: i wouldnt rely upon the `required` input html to make sure the input is filled out. (Nor would i rely on any front end code to guarantee you get good data submitted). So I would suggest changing the `name` attribute so that they are different from one another ie. `category_existing` and `category_new`.. and then when you're processing your form server side kick back error messages for content that is either incorrect or not there.. having said the first bit though, i would recommend something like jQuery validate http://jqueryvalidation.org to provide some basics of what youre trying to do

Comment: This is within an Intranet environment with only one possible validated admin user though.

Comment: ok, in which case i would lose the `required` and do your front end validation purely with js, using different `name` attributes for each.. but make sure you do also have backend validation (user error should always be accounted for as best as possible)

Comment: The problem is the user is not very tech savvy so I have some css that shows that he has to fill out the Add Category field if he selects Add new category, so if I drop the validation, he can fill out the form with no value there. I am trying to make his job easier by flagging the required fields for the chosen action.

Comment: I have also tried:  $(["input:hidden, textarea:hidden, select:hidden"]).attr("disabled", false);

Comment: definitely still have front end validation. but you dont have to rely on browser based validation so much as javascript validation. By this i mean, use the jQuery Validation library i linked in my first comment to process the form as your user progresses through the form. but by using JS you can toggle the necessity of the `required` state based upon the input inside your `categoryType` select box.. see http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method and it's `dependency` variable

Comment: in you "also tried" comment.. try using `.prop()` instead of `attr` as reads from page load where as `prop` fetches at runtime.. see just a little down from the first 2 yellow highlighted sections on this page http://api.jquery.com/attr/